# Is there a fee for cancelling a building?

Tags: starcraft-2

I always thought that if you cancelled a building while it's being built, you got all your mineral back, but [I read](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Extractor_Trick) that the extractor trick for zerg costs 6 minerals when you cancel it.

Does this apply to all buildings/races? How is that fee calculated?

Comment: Since there is nothing which costs 1 mineral for Zerg, some people short hand this cost to 10.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You get 75% back of the cost, minerals and gas. So if you cancel a building that costs 200 minerals and 100 gas, you'll get back 150 minerals and 75 gas.

An extracter cost 25 minerals, 25% of it is 6 (after rounding), so that's what you lose for canceling it.

Notice that this only applies to buildings - canceling a unit or an upgrade gives back the full amount of minerals and gas spent.

Comment: Is this regardless of how long the structure/unit has been in production?

Comment: @Brant correct, it doesn't matter how long it has been in production.

Comment: wow, I never realized I wasn't getting all my minerals back...

Comment: Is this exclusive to zerg buildings or does it apply to all races?

Comment: @Raven this applies to all buildings, including Terran building add-ons.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer:  Salvaging a bunker is one case that is similar to canceling but gets you 100% of your minerals back. It is the closest thing to an exception that I can think of.

Comment: @peter salvaging requires the building be finished. Canceling always has a price.

Comment: @tzenes heh that's why i said it was similar not the same :)