# How much does it cost to cancel a building/unit/add-on?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a fee for cancelling a building?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/is-there-a-fee-for-cancelling-a-building)

How much does it cost to cancel a building/unit/add-on? By this I mean, if a barracks costs 150 minerals and I started building one, what amount of minerals is returned if I cancel the building?

This question also applies to add-ons and units.

I saw that salvaging a bunker returned 100 minerals. Is this true? It doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Shouldn't cancelling a building probably return all funds spent?

Comment: Related: [on cancel cost of buildings](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/is-there-a-fee-for-cancelling-a-building).

Comment: More then related; a duplicate really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Building/Canceling buildings returns 75% of the resources
- I'm not sure about add-ons but I think it's 75% as they are buildings; this is easy to test
- Canceling building units returns 100% resources
- Salvaging is unrelated; it's a special building feature